# node_modules path can't be found

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, node-modules

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

In my index.html, I am trying to access a specific js in node_modules.

I've tried these:

```
<script src="./node_modules/ng-currency/dist/ng-currency.js"></script>

<script src="../node_modules/ng-currency/dist/ng-currency.js"></script>

<script src="../../node_modules/ng-currency/dist/ng-currency.js"></script>
```

None worked, it only worked when I copied node_modules folder to public folder, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No every javascript file you refer to in a client-side js file needs to be in the public folder!

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Consider webpack, rollup, or browserify

Comment: So wait....are you saying that node_modules must always be inside public folder by default?  so when I am installing new packages I should install them always inside public?

Comment: You could just copy the ng-currency.js file into the public folder or dive deep and learn to use browserify

Answer (score 0):

You could export it as a static asset in your `app.js` file and then use it in the `html` as you are already doing. If you're using `express` then it's pretty straight-forward.

app.js:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/ng-currency/dist/')));
```

html:

```
<script src="/scripts/ng-currency.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```